# Bluetooth mesh for Raspberry Pi using python

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mesh-network

Do you guys know any tutorials about working with Bluetooth mesh using python that I can study? I am planning to connect 3 Raspberry Pi using Bluetooth mesh that will only send strings of characters. I already did it using wifi but Bluetooth is needed also to be implemented. I am searching online but I am having a hard time seeing any tutorials about it. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for the BlueZ (The Bluetooth stack used on RPi) API is at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mesh-api.txt

They have a Python example in the source tree:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-mesh

The Bluetooth SIG have an article introducing Bluetooth MESH:

https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/an-intro-to-bluetooth-mesh-part1/

As well as some study guides they have written:

https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/?types=study-guide&categories=&tags=&keyword=mesh

silvair is an early adopter of of Bluetooth MESH and they have a python library at:

https://python-bluetooth-mesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Do you think the system I will be making above will work?

Comment: There is not enough information in the question for me to speculate. Generally speaking Bluetooth mesh topology is more complex and so is more difficult to build and maintain. Mesh has not been around very long so there are not the same level of tutorials available. You need to analyze if a simpler to implement topology will do what you need.

Comment: Basically, I wanted to make 3 raspberry pi communicate to each other and just send a string of text from 1 pi to the other 2 at the same time. The same goes for the two other pi, they should be able to send a string to the other pi simultaneously.

Comment: I have done a client and server type of connection wherein it can send the string to the other pi. However, I think this is using the classic Bluetooth, I need to use BLE and have a minimum of 3 pis for the system. Can I use this client and server architecture with BLE? Is this type of architecture feasible with what I am doing or Bluetooth mesh is the way to go? I am sorry for the questions, I am a beginner with Bluetooth.

Comment: @ukBaz Could you clarify whether BlueZ allows a Linux device (Raspberry Pi) to be a complete fully functional BLE mesh node and directly send BLE mesh packets to other nodes?

Comment: Bluetooth Mesh makes heavy use of AEAD-AES_CCM encryption, which is implemented in the Linux kernel on most platforms. I haven't checked lately, but this was not enabled by default on Raspberry Pi so required a rebuilding the Kernel for BlueZ.  So it does not support it by default. This is the code in the example:  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-mesh#n685