# Is it possible to create a Bluetooth Mesh Network using python?

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-mesh

I'm doing a feasibility check for my idea, I want to be able to create a Bluetooth Mesh Network for a chat application

IE You have clients A - B - C, A cannot reach C so sends their message to B who forwards it to C

I need to do this using Bluetooth akin to how FireChat used to work: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireChat)

Is there any way to do this using Python? I've been searching for modules but all seem to be either unsupported or unsuitable

Comment: Have a look at this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561842/bluetooth-mesh-for-raspberry-pi-using-python